# Youtube: How to get all video IDs to a Channel / User? [V3]

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm kinda lost in the YouTube Data Api v3. Can you guys give me hints on how to get the video IDs to a given channel / user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

check the documentation for [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Videos for a channel

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId=UCIiJ33El2EakaXBzvelc2bQ&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

If you want the videos for the authenticated user.  It doesn't appear that you can search for videos by a user that is not authenticated . You cant just send the users id for example.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&forMine=true&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. For an actually authenticated user. I just want to get the video id of my videos and the comment count.

Comment: Once you are authenticated then you can get the list using the second one. Once you get a list of the videos you can run a second request against comments.list

Comment: Yeah. I have just found out. Thank you though.

Comment: Can you check whether this is working? I do get bad request 400. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list